# How to remove items from asp .net DropDown that already bind from Enums value

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have a dropdown & binding with enum value.

```
ddlDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Resources.Default.PremiumNew, VoucherType.PremiumNew.ToValue())); // value 20
ddlDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Resources.Default.SilverNew, VoucherType.SilverNew.ToValue())); // value 21
ddlDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Resources.Default.GoldNew, VoucherType.GoldNew.ToValue())); // value 22
```

Now i have another dynamic array value that is

```
int[] availableVoucherTypesArray = Array.ConvertAll(availableVoucherTypes.Split(','), int.Parse);
```

let array "availableVoucherTypesArray" value are 20 & 22 .I want to remove 21 value from dropdown. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me. Thanks !

```
 for (Int32 i = ddlDropDownList.Items.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
       {
            ListItem item = ddlDropDownList.Items[i];

            if (!availableVoucherTypesArray.Contains(int.Parse(item.Value)))
            {
                ddlDropDownList.Items.Remove(ddlDropDownList.Items.FindByValue(item.Value.ToString()));            
            }
       }
```